# How to prevent opening jqueryUI autocomplete drowpdown on fast entry

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jQueryUI autocomplete is added to input text element using code below in form.
If text is entered and tab pressed rapidly, cursor moves to other column but autocomplete menu remains open.

How to prevent opening autocomplete menu in this case.
Probably blur event should terminate autocomplete drowpdowm menu data retrieval call so that
dropdown menu is not opened after data is received from server or something like ?
I tried to add input.autocomplete('close') to blur but this does not help.
Probably blur occurs before data is retrieved from server and before autocomplete is opened.

input contains input type='text' object reference.

```
input.autocomplete({
        source: 'GetLookupList',
        position: { collision: 'flip flip' }
    }
   );

$(input).bind({
        keydown: function (e) {
            if (enter(e) || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83)) {
                input.autocomplete('close');
            }
        },
        blur: function (e) {
             input.autocomplete('close');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar issue where if I type really fast and hit enter before the auto complete comes up, when the partial post-back is completed, it'll display the drop down in the upper-left corner of the page.

Comment: I havent solved this. jquery ui autocomplete bug tracker contains similar issue and fix. You can try apply this fix, use jqueryui from svn or wait for next release (maybe jan 2012). Please let us know if you have new information about this.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a response in the comment section, but I wanted to attach some code.

I basically did the same thing as you and bound a `keydown` for the `enter` key closing the `autocomplete` then calling the `click` event on the button that's attached to the search box.

```
$('input[id$=MainSearchBox]').bind(
    {
        keydown: function(e)
        {
            if (e.which === 13)
            {
                $('input[id$=MainSearchBox]').autocomplete('close');
                $('input[id$=MainSearchBox]').autocomplete('disable');
                $('input[id$=MainSearchBoxGoButton]').click();
                e.preventDefault()
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Seems like the most straight forward thing one can do. I read some place about the fix coming in the next release, but for now, I think this solution would work.

EDIT: Updated the code to disable autocomplete, allow the click to go through, and when the `pageLoad` method it's contained in gets called on the partial post-back, it'll rebuild the autocomplete object. I worry it's probably not the smartest or most efficient way of doing it, but it seems to work...

Comment: I have similar code on my application. If users clicks rapidly in other cell, dropdows still remain open. blur cannot canceled and probably dropdown is opened after blur if server ajax call completes.

Comment: Thank you. This approach assumes that form is submitted. If Tab key is pressed rapidly to move to next field or clicked in other field, how to disable dropdown to appear in this case? Maybe it is possible to check if current autocomplete has focus in ajax call compete event or set property in blur event for dedecting this. Have you tried jquery ui autocomplate from git hub ?

Comment: Hi, did you both manage to find a fix for this? @Andrus or Emmanuel?

Comment: @RicL; The above worked for me at the time however, the module this was used for was scrapped for something else, so it all became a moot point. I think it'll work, but @Andrus has a point with the his last comment on fast tabbing.